# How to add extension method to IGrouping?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I created method like this:

```
private TProperty CheckElements<TElement, TProperty>(IGrouping<string, TElement> group, Func<TElement, TProperty> propertySelector)
```

and i invoke it like this inside `Select` done after `GroupBy` (gr is IGrouping inside select):

```
val = CheckElements(gr, x => x.SomeProperty)
```

**How can i extend IGrouping?** So that i can just:

```
val = gr.CheckElements(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

Comment: Define it as an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). In particular, it needs to be a static method inside a static class, and the first parameter needs to be `this IGrouping<...> group)`

Comment: Oh i thought there will be a problem because its interface and interface can't have any implementations, i didn't even try, silly me. Thank you ^^

Comment: All of linq, including `GroupBy`, is defined as extension methods

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
  static class Extension
{
    public static TProperty CheckElements<TElement, TProperty>(this IGrouping<string, TElement> group,
        Func<TElement, TProperty> propertySelector)
    {
      ...
    }

 
}
```